# How to combine two observable arrays of the same type in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I cannot seem to figure out how to combine two observable arrays. This is using Angular 6, rxjs 6.3.2

Example code:

```
var arrayOfUsers = this.httpCallToGetObservableArrayOfUsers();
var anotherArrayOfUsers = this.httpCallToGetADifferentArrayOfUsers();

//how do I combine these two Observable<User[]>?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/

Comment: did you tried concat arrayOfUsers.pipe(concat(anotherArrayOfUsers )).subscribe((response)=>{}); ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your observables are http calls, I assume they complete after emitting.
you can use forkJoin to combine them:

```
var arrayOfUsers = this.httpCallToGetObservableArrayOfUsers();
var anotherArrayOfUsers = this.httpCallToGetADifferentArrayOfUsers();

const allUsersArray = forkJoin(arrayOfUsers, anotherArrayOfUsers).pipe(
    map(([users, otherUsers]) => users.concat(otherUsers))
);
```

if your observables do not complete, use combineLatest:

```
const allUsersArray = combineLatest(arrayOfUsers, anotherArrayOfUsers).pipe(
    map(([users, otherUsers]) => users.concat(otherUsers))
);
```